# Saber cuando la App es lanzada por primera vez en Android

Tags: java, android

¿Cómo se puede saber si es la primera vez que se inicia la app?

Seria interesante, en el caso que el usuario actualice la aplicación se detecte como nueva o update.

Comment: Del sitio en inglés: [Determine if android app is the first time used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4636141/1065197)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si más o menos es lo que necesito, veo que me descuidado en especificar que se tenga en cuenta la versión de la app, así si el usuario actualiza la app se vuelve a detectar.

Comment: Me han recomendado la librería Once, es muy versatil para todo proposito iniciales https://github.com/jonfinerty/Once

Comment: Puedes publicar una nueva respuesta con un ejemplo de esa librería. Y sí, está permitido que publiques más de una respuesta, inclusive a tu propia pregunta.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza pues entonces, voy a mirar si hago un pequeño ejemplo y lo publico.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Puedes usar *Shared Preferences* para guardar valores de manera persistente. Entonces podrías guardar una variable que contenga el nombre de la versión del app y comprobarlo cada vez que arranque la aplicación. Además, las Shared Preferences se mantienen incluso después de actualizar, así que este método serviría también para detectar la primera ejecución tras una actualización.

La idea sería que tuvieras una constante con la versión de la aplicación (por ejemplo un String del tipo "1.0.0"). Y luego seguir un algoritmo como éste al arrancar la aplicación:

1. Lee el valor de la versión en *Shared Preferences* (o inicializa a cadena vacía si no existe)
2. Si el valor de la constante es diferente al valor de *Shared Preferences* del paso 1, entonces es la primera vez que se inicia la app:

   - Si el valor en leído es la cadena vacía (""), entonces es la primera vez tras la instalación.
   - Si es diferente a la cadena vacía, entonces es la primera vez tras una actualización.
3. Guardar el valor de la constante con la versión en las *Shared Preferences*.

Comment: Me ha servido de base en crear la función

Answer (score 6):

**Solventado**, cogiendo ideas de las respuestas:

```
private int getFirstTimeRun() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MYAPP", 0);
    int result, currentVersionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
    int lastVersionCode = sp.getInt("FIRSTTIMERUN", -1);
    if (lastVersionCode == -1) result = 0; else
        result = (lastVersionCode == currentVersionCode) ? 1 : 2;
    sp.edit().putInt("FIRSTTIMERUN", currentVersionCode).apply();
    return result;
}
```

Los valores que devuelve la función:

- 0: la App no se ha ejecutado nunca.
- 1: la App alguna vez se ha ejecutado.
- 2: la App se ha ejecutado alguna vez, pero no esa versión.

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```
switch(getFirstTimeRun()) {
    case 0:
        Log.d("appPreferences", "Es la primera vez!");
        break;
    case 1:
        Log.d("appPreferences", "ya has iniciado la app alguna vez");
        break;
    case 2:
        Log.d("appPreferences", "es una versión nueva");
}
```

Se acepta mejoras de funcionalidad y optimización de código.

**EDITADO**

Otra manera es usar la librería [Once](https://github.com/jonfinerty/Once) :

Inicializar con: `Once.initialise(this);`

**Métodos primera vez:**

La primera vez que el usuario instala la app:

```
if (!Once.beenDone(Once.THIS_APP_INSTALL, "tag")) {
    //Primera vez que se instala la app
    Once.markDone("tag");
}
```

La primera vez despues de upgrade de la app:

```
if (!Once.beenDone(Once.THIS_APP_VERSION, "tag")) {
    //Primera vez despues de actualizar la app
    Once.markDone("tag");
}
```

**ACTUALIZADO ABRIL 2017**

También hay la posibilidad de obtener si es una instalación de 0 o bien una update, obteniendo los valores del APK

```
public static boolean isFirstInstall(Context context) {
    try {
        long firstInstallTime =   context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).firstInstallTime;
        long lastUpdateTime = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).lastUpdateTime;
        return firstInstallTime == lastUpdateTime;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}



public static boolean isInstallFromUpdate(Context context) {
    try {
        long firstInstallTime =   context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).firstInstallTime;
        long lastUpdateTime = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).lastUpdateTime;
        return firstInstallTime != lastUpdateTime;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Se puede usar **[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)**, hay que tomar en cuenta que estos valores pueden perderse cuando desinstalas la aplicación .

Puedes guardar mediante el método `setInicia()`, enviando el valor de 1 cuando es la primera instalación y puedes obtener el valor de esa preferencia mediante el método `getInicia()`

```
public static int getInicia(Context ctx){
    response = ctx.getSharedPreferences("INSTALACION", 0)
                                       .getInt("primeravez", 0);
return response;
}

public static void setInicia(Context ctx, int mode){
        ctx.getSharedPreferences("INSTALACION", 0).edit()
                                .putInt("primeravez", mode).commit();
}
```

Sin embargo si quieres definir la primera ocasión que inicia la aplicación en un dispositivo, el método (aunque también no es del todo infalible) que uso es escribir un archivo conteniendo el string "1", dentro del directorio `/Android/data` y no dentro del directorio de la aplicación `/Android/data/com.midominio.miapp`

```
File installation = new File(getExternalInstallPath(context));
try {
    if (!installation.exists()){
        createInstallDirectory(context);                    
        writeInstallationFile(installation);                        
    }
    sID = readInstallationFile(installation);
    Log.i(TAG, "el status de la instalación es: " + sID);
} catch (Exception e) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Estos son los métodos utilizados:

```
private static void writeInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(installation, false);
   String id = "1";
   Log.i(TAG, "Writing Installation File: " + id);
   out.write(id.getBytes());
   out.close();
}    

private static String readInstallationFile(File installation) throws IOException {
   RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(installation, "r");
   byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) f.length()];
   f.readFully(bytes);
   f.close();

   return new String(bytes);
}

public static File createInstallDirectory(Context ctx) throws IOException {
   String directoryPath=getExternalInstallPath(ctx);
   File dir = new File(directoryPath);
   if (dir.exists()) {
       return dir;
   }
   if (dir.mkdirs()) {
       return dir;
   }
   throw new IOException("Failed to create INSTALL '" + directoryPath + "' for an unknown reason.");
}

public static String getExternalInstallPath(Context ctx){
   String directoryPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
   directoryPath = directoryPath + "/Android/data/");
   return directoryPath;
}
```

Comment: ¿Con lo de getExternalInstallPath si el dispositivo no tiene SD card, coge como referencia la interna?
Y supongo que el usuario en caso de desinstalar la app, esos datos persisten, si no se borran

Comment: Los datos permanecen si desinstalas la aplicación ya que se elimina unicamente lo que existe dentro de /Android/data/com.midominio.miapp.

Answer (score 0):

En flutter se hace de esta forma... con la dependencia
shared_preferences: ^2.1.0

```
var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var isFirstTime = prefs.getBool('first_time') ?? true;
```

para indicar que ya iniciaste por primera vez

```
pref!.setBool(IntroScreen.INTRO_SEEN, false);
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Para usar Flutter se programa en Dart y la pregunta es sobre Java. ¿Estás seguro sobre tu respuesta?

Comment: hola mateo, gracias, si asi lo tengo funcionando en unas app que tengo, es lo mas sencillo que he conseguido hacer