# Saber cuando la App es lanzada por primera vez en IOS

Tags: ios, swift2, swift

Esta pregunta está en [`Android`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3243/saber-cuando-la-app-es-lanzada-por-primera-vez-en-android), pero ¿cómo seria en `iOS`?

¿Cómo se puede saber si es la primera vez que se inicia la app?

Seria interesante, en el caso que el usuario actualice la aplicación se detecte como nueva o update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En objective C :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

En swift usando NSUserDefault :

```
 let launchedBefore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("launchedBefore")
if launchedBefore  {
    print("anteriormente iniciada.")
}
else {
    print("Se inicia por primera vez!..")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
}
```

Comment: Por curiosidad más que nada, ¿importa si es swift o swift2?

Comment: En algunos casos cambia la sintaxis. En este caso usando Swift 2 también se puede usar la clase  NSUserDefault.

Answer (score 1):

Completando la respuesta, primero llenas la variable

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] introducir el código aquíboolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Para leer luego la variable si lo necesitas en algún lado

```
 NSString *value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Añado el código para Swift 4

**Guardar datos:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(<value>, forKey: "key_name")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize() //Optional
```

**Recuperar datos**

```
var returnValue: [datatype]? = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "key_name") as? [datatype]
```

Y añado también como **borrarlos**, que en las anteriores respuestas no está:

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey:"key_name")
```