# Mensaje de bienvenida al actualizar aplicación

Tags: android

He tenido esta duda desde hace mucho, la primera vez que mi aplicacion inicia que la instalas por primera vez me sale un cartel de novedades. Ahora he visto aplicaciones que lo hacen cada vez que la actualizas. Como podria hacer eso?? Gracias de antemano. Esto es lo que he creado como hago para que cuando actualice esto vuelva a salir con la info cambiada?

```
if (firstRun()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Novedades en la versión " + obtenerVersionApp());
        builder.setMessage(""); // mensaje con las novedades
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Has visto [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/3243/250)? Creo que podría ser de ayuda. Se explica cómo detectar si la aplicación se está ejecutando por primera vez o como actualización para realizar operaciones especiales.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro porque no me publicas una respuesta para marcarla como solucion?

Comment: La verdad es que fuera de lo que puse en la otra pregunta, no sé mucho del tema (y personalmente las otras respuestas son más completas). Si las respuestas de la otra pregunta te valen, podemos marcar esta como duplicada o puedes escribir una con detalles de cómo lo hiciste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente puedes mostrar la primera vez que actualizaste tu aplicación el mensaje o dialogo y tienes que definir en tu aplicación que únicamente se muestra en la primera ocasión, para esto puedes usar `SharedPreferences`.

Para esto puedes encontrar información en la pregunta que indica @AlvaroMontoro.

[Saber cuando la App es lanzada por primera vez en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3243/saber-cuando-la-app-es-lanzada-por-primera-vez-en-android)

Ahora para mostrar las nuevas características de tu aplicación puedes usar como opción [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView):

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView

Aquí puedes mostrar un mensaje de bienvenida, agregar textos relacionados a nuevos features y dar enfoque a los controles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Su uso en realidad es sencillo:

```
 ShowcaseView showcaseView = new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
    .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
    .setContentTitle("Novedades en la versión " + obtenerVersionApp())
    .setContentText("Bienvenido a esta nueva versión!")
    .hideOnTouchOutside()
    .build();
```

Te sugiero revisar el ejemplo:

https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/tree/master/sample